# How to not fire throttle function from lodash?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a throttle function from lodash in my React project. If the length of the parameter `value` is zero, the function should not be executed.

Can anyone help me with that? I already started checking the length of value and saying `throttling(false)` but that doesn't work.

```
const throttling = useCallback(
throttle(function(value) {
  if (value.length > 0) {
    const myFetch = fetch(fetchApi + encodeURIComponent(value))
    myFetch.then(response => response.json()).then(setSearchResult)
  } else {
    console.log('0')
  }
}, 500),
[]
```

)

```
function handleChange(event) {
   throttling(event.target.value)
   onChange(event.target.value)
}
```

Comment: what should be the searchResult when value has length 0. If you do not fire the throttling function how do you get the result when user deleted the search keyword

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you go the other way around?

```
function handleChange(event) {
    if (event.target.value.length > 0) {
        throttling(event.target.value)
    }
    onChange(event.target.value)
}
```

This way the function only fires if the value is above 0 and does nothing if that is not the case.

**EDIT**:
If you want to fire the function always, this would be an alternative approach:

```
  const throttling = (value) => {
    const myFetch = fetch(
      "http://localhost:8000/api/auto-suggest?input=" +
        encodeURIComponent(value)
    );

    useCallback(
      value.length > 0
        ? myFetch.then(response => response.json()).then(setSearchResult)
        : throttle(function(value) {
            myFetch.then(response => response.json()).then(setSearchResult);
          }, 500),
      []
    );
  };

  function handleChange(event) {
    throttling(event.target.value);
    onChange(event.target.value);
  }
```

The check is now in the use callback function and will use `throttle` if the lenght of the value is bigger than 0.

Comment: Yeaah but with this solution when the value is empty it doesn' t make a call to the backend. The earlier call stays visible.

Comment: Then you would have to move the check into the throttling function.

Comment: Like between the function and the const myFetch?

Comment: I don't exactly use your example. But added the if inside the throttle functie. But now in the else i need to reset the fetch call i earlier did when the `value.length` was above 0. What exactly do I need to write to reset the earlier API call?

Comment: Can you update your example? I don't really know what you mean?

Comment: So you want to do the earlier call again? Shouldn't it still be displayed as it was the last one?

Comment: Euhhm no i don't think so. Because i want to use he `throttle` all the time but the fetch call only when the value is above 0. In your example you use `useCallback` in the wrong way. Because `throttling` is a function not a component